# Personalized Listview error on set background color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors, adapter

i have a problem in my app:
i use a listview with a personalized adapter,
in this adapter i want to change the color of the line depending on whether the message is read or not.

In the metod  GETVIEW i control a variable, if it is equal to 0 i want to change the background color.

All works and the list is displayed as i want,

but  when there are a lot of elements and the list is scrolled in any direction (from top to bottom and vice versa) the raws are displeyed with the same color even if by code is set another color.

Has anyone ever had the same problem? 
You can advise me something about it?

There is the code of my Adapter:

```
public class LazyAdapterComunicazioni extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] id;
    private String[] titolo;
    private String[] data;
    private String[] letto;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    //public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapterComunicazioni(Activity a, String[] idCom, String[] titoloCom,      String[] dataCom, String[]lettoCom) {
        activity = a;
        id = idCom;
        titolo = titoloCom;
        data = dataCom;
        letto = lettoCom;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return id.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comunicazionicslist, null);
        }

        ContactsViewHolder viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder();

        //Settimane
        viewHolder.txtTitolo=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_Titolo);
        viewHolder.txtTitolo.setText(titolo[position].toString());

        //Data
        viewHolder.txtData=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_Data);
        viewHolder.txtData.setText(data[position].toString());

        //ID
        viewHolder.txtID=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_ID);
        viewHolder.txtID.setText(id[position].toString());

        //Connessianne e Apretura del DB
        String read = letto[position].toString();

        if (read.equals("0")) //DA LEGGERE
        {
            //LAYOUT
            viewHolder.rel = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_RIGA); 
            viewHolder.rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondorigacomcs);
            viewHolder.txtTitolo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }   

        return vi;
    }

    static class ContactsViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitolo;
        TextView txtData;
        TextView txtID;
        RelativeLayout rel;
    }
}
```

and the xml of the single row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/comCS_RIGA"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comCS_Data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comCS_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comCS_Data"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comCS_Titolo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comCS_Data"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#357cbc"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/feedbackCars_Positivo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/frecciacom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_Comunicazioni"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common error.
Views are recycled so you have to set back default values in any cases.

```
    if (read.equals("0")) //DA LEGGERE
    {
        //LAYOUT
        viewHolder.rel = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_RIGA); 
        viewHolder.rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondorigacomcs);
        viewHolder.txtTitolo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }   
   else {
        viewHolder.rel.setBackgroundResource("you_defaulf_bg_res");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **you are not using the ViewHolder pattern correctly**. The ViewHolder is designed to hold references to the Views of the list-item and **minimize** the `findViewById(...)` calls.

That purpose is not fulfilled by your code. **The reason for the behaviour you described lies in the Views not being recycled.**

Do it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ContactsViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comunicazionicslist, null);
        viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder();

        viewHolder.txtTitolo=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_Titolo);
        viewHolder.txtData=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_Data);
        viewHolder.txtID=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_ID);

        viewHolder.rel = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.comCS_RIGA); 

        vi.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ContactsViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    //Settimane
    viewHolder.txtTitolo.setText(titolo[position].toString());

    //Data
    viewHolder.txtData.setText(data[position].toString());

    //ID
    viewHolder.txtID.setText(id[position].toString());

    //Connessianne e Apretura del DB
    String read = letto[position].toString();

    if (read.equals("0")) //DA LEGGERE {

        viewHolder.rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondorigacomcs);
        viewHolder.txtTitolo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.NORMAL_BACKGROUND);
    }

    return vi;
}
```